# How to handle routerLink and (click) received from Input()

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to be able to handle `routerLink` and `(click)` logic passed in `Input()` as `string`.

Here's what I have:

In file `example.component.ts` I have:

```
this.data = {
  render: () => {
    return `
      <a [routerLink]="details/31">AAA</a>
      <div (click)="doConsole()">BBB</div>    
    `
  }
]

doConsole() {
  console.log('something');
}
```

In `example.component.html`:

```
  <app-my-table [data]="data"></app-my-table>
```

File `my-table.component.html`:

```
<div [innerHTML]="renderData()></div>
```

And `my-table.component.ts`:

```
renderData() {
  return data.render()
}
```

I was hoping that when I click on `<a>` with `AAA` I'll go to `details/31`, and when I click on `<div>` with `BBB` I'll see `'something'` in console.

None of this happends. There's even no "routerLink" or "(click)" in the html when I inspect it in browser.

I've tried to modify `renderData` function this way:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

renderData() {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml;
}
```

and with this I can see "routerLink" and "(click)" in browser, but clicking on them does nothing.

How can I handle situation like this?

Comment: I've never seen this syntax before. Why do you use a `data` variable to inject code ? Have you tried to use <ng-content> for content injection ?

Comment: @Random in general - yes, but I don't think I can use it here. I simplified the question, but in real example `data` is an array and I'm iterating over it, so I call `renderData` multiple times, and as I know `ng-content` is for 1-time use.

Comment: I don’t get this code either. What is the main purpose of it please explain

Comment: I want to make a table. I'm getting data from outside. Each table column has `render` method which tells what kind of html should be rendered. In the end `<td>` could have a `<div>` which should work with  `routerLink` or `(click)`, but it doesn't.

Comment: I think you are missing how you should do it in Angular. You should never write html using javascript. You should be able to do anything with `*ngFor` and `<ng-content>`